# Convert minutes into proper dates

Tags: matlab, date, datetime, minute

I have a vector (X) of 525599. Each value represent every minute of the year 2010 (365 days). 
Let's clarify:

```
X        date
1         1/1/2010 00:01:00
2         1/1/2010 00:02:00
3         1/1/2010 00:03:00
...
525599   31/12/2010 23:58:00
525599   31/12/2010 23:50:00
```

How can I convert the consecutive numbers in X in a format similar to the second column (DDMMYYYY HH:MM)?

Comment: http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html do you mean something like this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have MATLAB version 2014b or later, then the simplest and best option is to make use of the new [`datetime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/date-and-time-operations.html) datatype:

```
datetime('2010-01-01') + minutes(X)
```

On older versions use:

```
datestr(datenum('2010-01-01') + X/(24*60))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to take your time as Epoch and then convert it into date time:

```
epoch_mil = 1262304000000 + X*1000*60; % 2010/01/01 00:00:00.000 + your Minutes 
reference = datenum('1970', 'yyyy'); 
time = reference + epoch_mil / 8.64e7;
time_as_string = datestr(time, 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS')


>> X = 1:4;
time_as_string =

2010/01/01 00:01:00
2010/01/01 00:02:00
2010/01/01 00:03:00
2010/01/01 00:04:00
```